# How do you export a font from Glyphs

Tags: fonts, icon

I just made some small tweaks to an OTF icon-font (iconic) and now I'm having trouble exporting this modified font.  Have I missed something? Can you export from Glyphs to an OTF or TTF?

Comment: Hello, welcome to GD.SE. While not unwelcome here, your question would probably get a quicker response from the [Glyphs Forums](http://glyphsapp.com/forums/). If you get an answer from there, feel free to post it here.

Answer (score 2):

Glyphs can export to OTF, UFO, and PHF formats. There's also experimental support for TTF format.

To export, go to `File` >> `Export` and then choose any options and/or the output directory.

[image]